# How to make a button choose a random spot on the screen - android

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to make a button(that is shaped like a circle) choose a random spot *within the users screen* and stay there until, obviously the next activity starts. I have found a lot of people wanting to do this but none of the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Java's `Random` and generate two numbers with limits of the screen size and then set the LayoutParams of a button like this

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAPCONTENT, AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams,
    myNewX, myNewY));
```

Comment: I get two errors as follows:

AbsoluteLayout is deprecated

LayoutParams cannot be resolved to a variable (but ony the one @ AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams,
    myNewX, myNewY));

Comment: change it to ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I haven't done any Android programming in a while so i am behind on whats deprecated.

Comment: Anyone else have an answer?